# draw straight line from one point to another in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to draw a straight line from one point to another,as the user drags finger. So, I can draw the line. But if I try to add the draw next line, the first drawn line vanishes.

```
Override
    public void pointerDragged(int x, int y) {
        super.pointerDragged(x, y);
        if (MainMenuScreen.inSentFolder()) {
            return;
        }

        //adjust by taking off absolute x and y
        if (photoImage == null) {
            x = x - getX();

            y = y - getY();

            //adjust by viewerOffsets
            x = x - viewerXOffset;
            y = y - viewerYOffset;
        }
        else {

            x = x - imageDrawnFromX;
            y = y - imageDrawnFromY;
        }
     if(shapeType == ShapeTypes.LINE) {
     // it holds the x/y co-ordinates value as user drags from one point to another.
                    model.addLine(lastXPos,  lastYPos,  x, y, brushCol, brushGirth, brushShapeSize, imageToUse == null? -1 : imageToUse.getWidth(), imageToUse == null ? -1 : imageToUse.getHeight(), ShapeTypes.LINE,true);

                }

            }

            invalidate();       
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getInfo().size(); i++) {
            Line currentLine = (Line) model.getInfo().elementAt(i);
            g.setColor(currentLine.col);
            boolean drawme=false;

                        if(currentLine.guideLineOnly && (i == 
                                graffitiModel.getInfo().size() - 1))
                            drawme = true;

                        if(!currentLine.guideLineOnly)
                            drawme = true;

                        if(drawme) {
                          p.moveTo(currentLine.startX + imageDrawnFromX, currentLine.startY + imageDrawnFromY);
                          p.lineTo(currentLine.endX + imageDrawnFromX, currentLine.endY + imageDrawnFromY);
                        }

                            g.drawShape(p, stroke);
    }
```

Please help me on this, because I able to draw, it just vanishes when I try to draw second line.
Thanks

Comment: It looks there are some things missing from a big block of code. I suggest verifying that the model includes all the lines then verifying that when you loop in the paint method all the lines are added to the shape. Make sure you have different shapes for the lines and the highlight but you can use one shape object for all the permanent lines